# calculus: no limit vs. limit at infinity

Tags: calculus

Making progress.  I understand that there is no limit at zero for: sin(1/x) although we can be sure that if we were to say something about the graph, we would say that at x=0, y is between negative one and positive one.  But I'm told that for: x^2/x^4, we say the limit is at positive infinity. Now this might be splitting hairs, but it seems to me that whereas we have this word 'infinity' it does not actually indicate any point, since we never get to infinity. So, since the point f(x) when x=0 does not exist, how can this be called a limit?  Is it perhaps sufficient that the left and right hand halves of the graph do get infinitely close as we move infinitely far up the asymptote?  But if that were so, in the case of sin(1/x), we can likewise say that as we get infinitely close to the axis, f(x) does retain real values.  So how is that conceptually different from chasing infinity?

Comment: Have you seen how having a "limit of infinity as $x$ approaches $c$" is actually defined?  The point is that for any large number $M$ we think of, we can find some $\delta>0$ such that for all $x$ if $0<|x-c|<\delta$ then $f(x)>M$.  Indeed, we can do just that for $\frac{x^2}{x^4}$.

Comment: Sounds like my question will be addressed later.